# OpenCV Stitcher

Tags: python, opencv

I have a stepper motor that moves around a camera. I'm writing some python software that moves the stepper motor and takes a picture, then stitches the image to the previously stitched image. This seems to work well, but eventually OpenCV's stitcher fails to stitch images after taking 7-8 images.

The question is why does it eventually fail? What can I do to fix it?

Summary of code:

move stepper,
take pic1.jpg
move stepper,
take pic2.jpg stitch with pic1.jpg call it final.jpg,
move stepper,
take pic3.jpg stitch with final.jpg,
move stepper,
take pic4.jpg stitch with final.jpg,
...,
fail to stitch pic8.jpg with final.jpg

```
    stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
    newImg = cv2.imread(imageFile)
    stitchedImg = cv2.imread("final.jpg")
    result = stitcher.stitch((stitchedImg,newImg))
    cv2.imwrite("final.jpg", result[1])
    #code example of functions I'm using
```

thanks!

Comment: How does it fail? (Is there an error?) What do your images look like?

Comment: result[1] is None, instead of a array([...])

Comment: The images are very simple circles and simple text (think of black ink on white paper)